# OS X program won't compile EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I'm trying to learn XCode and Mac programming. I'm trying a program from a book on XCode 4, and I'm using 4.2.1. I've been told that the error isn't the tagged line of code below. How/where can I de-bug this? A search didn't turn up anything I understood.

In main.m - "Thread1 Program received signal 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,(const_char **)argv); //error here   
}
```

I don't find a Stack Navigator in View|Navigators.

[image]

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

[image]

I deleted the whole project and started over. Now I get a SIGABRT on the same line. Searching on that hasn't led to any resolution.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS isn't a compile error. Also, use `const char` instead of `const_char`.

Comment: Your program compiles just fine. Notice that this error doesn't show up in the Issues Navigator, which should be empty (and if it isn't, then you have some other things to fix!). Compile errors and debugger indicators look different; what you're seeing is the latter.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the whole Xcode window, with the Debugger Console visible and the Stack Navigator visible and set to full expansion (slider all the way to the right).

Comment: I edited to add the screen shot, but I don't see it now. I cannot find a Stack Navigator.

Comment: WTP - The underscore is a typo. XCode is putting a character that looks like a tiny 'U' in the whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zombie objects are great for debugging bad access.

In Xcode 4.1 and above, there's also checkbox on the "Diagnostics" tab of the "Run" stage to "Enable Zombie Objects".
 - from [How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

I found it very helpful to add an exception break point (via the + button in the lower left corner in the Breakpoint Navigator and set it to break on all exceptions when thrown. Click on the blue arrow in the list to switch it on and off as you need it. It will stop right at the source code position that threw the exception.

Answer (score -5):

```
 return NSApplicationMain(argc,(const_char *)argv);
```

get rid of 2nd asterisk

Comment: The 2nd asterisk is required.